Strange Behavior of EnableWindow on Button
I have a simple Win32 application that creates a button. Right after the button is created i disabled it using the EnableWindow(FALSE) function from the <windows.h>. It works normal when the button size is greater than the text applied.
But when the button size is smaller that the text of the button the client area of the entire window seems to copy the contents of the screen.


Code that causes the bug:
#include <Windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance, _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine, _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcex = { 0 };

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.lpszClassName = L"MYWINDOWCLASS";
    
    if (RegisterClassExW(&wcex) == 0)
        return -1;

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW(L"MYWINDOWCLASS", L"MYWINDOW", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);

    if (!hWnd)
        return -1;

    HWND buttonHWnd = CreateWindowW(L"BUTTON", L"MYWINDOW", WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,
        100, 100, 40, 30, hWnd, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);

    if (!buttonHWnd)
        return -1;

    EnableWindow(buttonHWnd, FALSE);

    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}



Your code is incomplete for two reasons: 1. You have not declared a background brush in your WNDCLASSEX structure, so you may not get the background you expect. 2. You do not have a handler for WM_PAINT messages, so whatever shows on the background of the window is not guaranteed.

"It works normal when the button size is greater than the text applied." - it actually doesn't. It may seem fine initially, however if you force window to repaint itself (for example by resizing it or minimizing/restoring), background will be messed up. So you should either provide background brush when registering window class or draw it yourself.

The default background brush actually solve it. I added wcex.hbrBackground = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 255, 255)); in the WNDCLASSEX and now it works fine. It also solve some other problems when resizing like @user7860670 said. Thanks a lot!!

@OldBoy that should be posted as an answer instead of a comment

@RemyLebeau It would probably need a more detailed explanation. And since the OP has solved his problem I will leave it as is for now.

As @RemyLebeau said, @OldBoy 's comment should be posted as an answer. Promote @OldBoy 's comment to answer.

Your code is incomplete for two reasons: 1. You have not declared a
background brush in your WNDCLASSEX structure, so you may not get the background you expect. 2. You do not have a handler for WM_PAINT
messages, so whatever shows on the background of the window is not
guaranteed.

